# Accessing SQL server from host machine on Oracle VM Virtualbox For SAS Programming

Tags: sas

I am using SAS University edition and want to access the data from SQL server on my host machine(Windows 8.1 64 bit) in my SAS code. Virtual Machine(Oracle VM Virtualbox) OS is also Windows 8.1 64 bit. I am getting following error.
ERROR: The product with which the engine ODBC is associated is either not licensed for your system or the product license has
expired. Please contact your SAS installation representative.

Comment: It's not officially supported but you can get it working. It's not a great set up. https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Analytics-U/Connect-to-SQL-Server-Oracle-Database-by-SAS-University-Edition/m-p/273857/highlight/true#M3724

Answer (score 0):

SAS UE can only use Access to PC Files. You will not be able to connect to a database. 
Either export/import your data manually via text files or try connecting an excel spreadsheet to your database.